# Android App - HttpURLConnection in onCreateView

Tags: java, android

I just started to learn developing android app, and I need to call an URL to get the JSON response.

Here is my java class :-

```
public class SpeakersFragment extends Fragment {

    List<String> titles;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_speakers, container, false);

        initData();
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.info_speaker_recycler);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), titles);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        new GetSpeakersList().execute(URL);

        return view;
    }


public class GetSpeakersList extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String> {
        String server_response;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    server_response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            Log.e("Response", "" + server_response);


        }
    }

    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

When I checked the logs, the response is not there at all. I tried creating a new project, it works fine if I call the GetSpeakersList in onCreate() instead of onCreateView.

Can guide me how to get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: try to start your asynctask in onActivityCreated() or onCreate() of your fragment

Answer (score 1):

Using an AsyncTask can be quite cumbersome to use for constant Network requests: Try using a popular, well-supported library for networking: Here are two popular ones:

1) [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

OR

2) [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: Though suggesting new libraries is good, I dont think this answer actually answers the question

Comment: The question stated that "I need to call an URL to get the JSON response". The OP did not say that they specifically wanted to use HttpURLConnection, but probably assumed they had to do so because they just started learning Android development. This informs them of other ways they can achieve the main objective.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i ask for data  hope you can use it to your means

```
urlConnection = new URL("www.example.com");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
connection.connect();

dataOutputStream = new 
DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
Log.d("OUTPUT :",param);
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(param);
dataOutputStream.flush();
dataOutputStream.close();
```

//incoming data

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(in));
result = new StringBuilder(16384);
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
  result.append(line);
}
Log.d("INPUT :",result.toString());
```